# Need help to configure jenkins to send report links on mail

Tags: email, reporting-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am using Jenkins to trigger my build., Jenkins is hosted on AmazonEC2. The complete build process is mentioned below:

```
1. Jenkins checkouts the latest build from GiTHub.
2. Jenkins run the complete build & I am getting Build Success Message.
3. After the process is completed jenkins creates some HTML reports in the jenkins user on Amazon EC2.
```

Now I need to send that particular report link in mail, how would I do that? Is there any plugins available by which I can manage all the reports generated for a single day and can keep the reports of last 15 builds or something.

What I can think of is, whenever a build completes, there should be a process or shell script should run which will copy the reports from jenkins user to some apache available sites and then that report can be sent on email.

please let me know, If I am thinking in the right direction or there is any other way to do the same?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins plugin ["Email-ext plugin"](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to send emails.

If you can get the report into your workspace. then, you can
write a mime message something like this in the plugin.

```
    msg.setSubject("Mail Subject");
    def reportPath = build.getWorkspace().child("report.html")
    msg.setContent(reportPath.readToString(),  "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```